# .net process.start() 32bit app on windows 7 64

Tags: .net, windows-7

We have created an application that changes the .ini files for a 3rd party app, so users at the enterprise level can access the various environments we have installed. This worked fine for us while using windows XP. I recently set out to make the application more windows 7 friendly, and look for the 3rd party app .ini file under c:\users\public.

The 3rd party app is installed and functioning correctly, but when we run the code below from a windows 7 machine it complains that it can not find its .ini files.

```
 manager.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 manager.StartInfo.FileName = iniChange.getBinPath() + "\\eimngr.exe";
 manager.Start();
 appOpen++;
 magOpen++;
```

I am wondering if we have missed setting some property of StartInfo or the Process.

Comment: If you run the app elevated (right click the exe, choose Run As Administrator) does it work?

Comment: Can you show the the code in Start() and possibly some specific examples of the results of getBinPath()?

Comment: What does the iniChange.getBinPath() do / return ?

Comment: Might also help - Reduce the UAC privledge. Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Change User Account Control Settings and reduce as necessary.

Comment: @SaifKhan No, don't do that. Fix your code or have your programs manifest request admin privileges. You should never lower the UAC settings.

Comment: It returns the program file path from the .ii file.

Comment: Not so sure its a permissions problem. 
I tried the working Directory property earlier, and retired based on your example to make sure I did not miss something, but no luck. As an experiment I coied eth .ini file from the c:\user\public\3rdPartyApp directory to c:\windows. The process started fine. So, is there something in the Process class that causes windows 7 to run application differently?

Comment: There is no code for .STart(). Its a method of the Process Class. The getBinPath returns the value of teh program install path from the .ini file. The application attempts to start, but fails because it can not find teh .ini file when started this way.

Comment: Also, just in case I was not clear. The 3rd party application starts fine by itself. Start->All Programs->App. It is just having problems when started from Process.Start(). Thanks to everyone for your questions so far.

Comment: Ok I have to eat some crow here. The Application runs fine when running the executable. The problem seems to be when you try to run it from the debugger in VS. Thanks again for everyone's responses. It made me think of some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the target application can not find the INI-file cause it uses relative pathes internally.
Try to set the working directory explicitly:

```
string targetFilePath = @"c:\folder\another_folder\myapp.exe";
string targetWorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFilePath);

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    WorkingDirectory = targetWorkingDirectory,
    FileName = targetFilePath,
};

Process targetProcess = new Process();
targetProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

targetProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// ...

targetProcess.Start();
```

Comment: I tried the working Directory property earlier, and retired based on your example to make sure I did not miss something, but no luck.
As an experiment I coied eth .ini file from the c:\user\public\3rdPartyApp directory to c:\windows. The process started fine. So, is there something in the Process class that causes  windows 7 to run application differently?

Comment: As far as I know there should be no difference. Can you provider an absoltute (sample) path to the target EXE + target INI files, please?